# Nested Checkboxes in a ListBox in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, listbox, observablecollection, nested-checkboxes

With Silverlight 4 as the technology platform, using an ObservableCollection as the ItemSource, assuming each item in the ObservableCollection has a property called SubLayers which contains children, what would the ListBox.ItemTemplate be such that the checkboxes in the listbox are nested in accordance with the ObservableCollection contents?

Answer (score 0):

> You can accomplish the same requirement with treeview using style sheet.

Comment: Are you referring to the tree-view-with-heirarchical-data-template approach?